# Fixed element in a susy grid not working in IE10

Tags: grid, fixed, css-position, susy-compass

I'm using Susy grids and utilizing the method described in this post [A `position:fixed` sidebar whose width is set in percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653827/a-positionfixed-sidebar-whose-width-is-set-in-percentage) to set a fixed sidebar. It work's well on Chrome but testing it out in IE10 the fixed sidebar end's up in the middle of the document. Can anyone see what's wrong here?

You can see it in action at:
http://dev-johandahl.com/gridtest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like IE10 is not centering the `.sidebar-area` container. That container is sitting flush left, so the right edge of it (the sidebar) falls in the middle of the page. There may be a better option, but the most obvious fix would be an additional wrapper around the sidebar container:

```
.sidebar-area {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center; // this may not be needed.

  .sidebar-container {
    @include container;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

That will set up an outer fixed area that is the full screen width, and you can center your container within that context. Let me know if you find a better solution!