# Set width of fixed positioned div relative to his parent having max-width

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is there any solution without JS?

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="fix"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5500px;
  position: relative;
}


.fix {
  width: inherit;
  height: 20px;
  position:fixed;
  background: black;
}
```

I cant add any other styles for `.wrapper` except `width: 100%;`.
I try with `width: inherit` but it doesn't work for me because of I have parent div with only max-width. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565/position-fixed-relative-to-parent-div)

Here is [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mx6anLuu/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `position:fixed` element is not relative to its parent anymore. It respects only the viewport's boudaries.

[**MDN Definition**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> **fixed** 
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled.

So any `width`, `max-width`, or whatever property will not be respected by the fixed element.

**EDIT**

In fact, it won't inherit the `width` because there's no `width` property defined on the wrapper.. So, try setting the child as `width: 100%` and inherit the `max-width`:

http://jsfiddle.net/mx6anLuu/2/

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 5500px;
    position: relative;
}


.fix {
    max-width: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position:fixed;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't mean that it won't inherit the `width` of parent by `inherit` value.

Comment: @HashemQolami, that's true... The truth is that it won't inherit the `width` because there's no `width` in the parent... I've updated the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you.  I think you should remove this "So any width, max-width, or whatever property will not be respected by the fixed element" because it's not strictly true: if the parent has a width then setting width: inherit (not width: 100%) on the fixed position child will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

there is already a width on the column, just set the width of the fixed element to inherit. no reason to complicate things.

CSS:

```
.col-sm-3 { width: 25%; }
.fixed-in-col { width: inherit; ... }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="fixed-in-div">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no solution without JS. 
This blog post by Felipe Tadeo explains why:

https://dev.to/phillt/inherit-the-width-of-the-parent-element-when-position-fixed-is-applied

It explains the confusion around `width: inherit`

"Fixed positions itself relative to the viewport... whenever you inherit width (with position fixed) it will be with respect to the viewport"