# Fixed width element taking its fluid parents size?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div inside a % width container.

HTML:

```
<div class="master-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fixed">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.master-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
    width: 30%;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

I've looked at a few other SO posts:

[Set width of a "Position: fixed" div relative to parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565/set-width-of-a-position-fixed-div-relative-to-parent-div)

[Set width of fixed positioned div relative to his parent having max-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999846/set-width-of-fixed-positioned-div-relative-to-his-parent-having-max-width)

With the general answer being to set `width: inherit` on the fixed element. The issue is it still inherits the width from the body rather than its percentage (unless I set a fixed width on the parent).

So, how can I get a fixed div to size to its immediate parent when the parent's width is set to a percentage.

I am seeking CSS solutions only - is it possible or will I have to JS it?

### Edit

Most solutions so far inherit the width of the page where I need to get the fixed div to take 30% of the mastered centered container that center's the web page, it has a max width of 1200px.

Comment: I think you'll need JS for this...

Comment: I am not sure I could understand what you are trying to achieve here, but as a first guess: https://codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/RLPQxd

Comment: Andrew Adam - close but not quite there, the codepen is incorrect its not taking width 30% of its parent, its take 30% of the body.

Comment: If you insist on using `position:fixed` then you will need javascript. Fixed elements are **always** related to the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "works" fine if your parent div is the same width as the body.  Of course, it is only working in appearance, not reality.  This div takes 30% of the browser's width, like its parent div.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(green, white)
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: inherit;
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, to accomplish this in CSS, you have a couple options, depending on your structure.

We know based on your question that the direct parent of the `fixed` div has a percentage width (we'll use `30%`). That `.container` div must have one or more parent divs that have:

1. A fixed width in pixels
2. A width in percentage
3. A width in vw, em, etc.

This will (probably) be calculated in CSS.  Otherwise, I don't know why you would want a CSS-only solution.

So if you have a parent of the container div with a width of `500px`, you can make your `fixed` div the same width as the `.container` by giving it 30% of 500px:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(blue, white)
}

.container {
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(green, white)
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: calc(500px * .3);
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fixed"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would also work if the `.parent` div has a width in `%` or `vw`, or anything else:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.parent {
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(blue, white)
}

.container {
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(green, white)
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: calc(50% * .3);
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fixed"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, you will have to know the widths of all the parents up to either the body or the nearest div with a fixed width and do the math in the CSS `calc` to adjust.  But again, assuming no JS and that all parent div widths are defined in CSS, this could be done.

**Edit:** based on your updated question:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.master-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: linear-gradient(blue, white)
}

.container {
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(green, white)
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: calc(1200px * .3);
    height: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .fixed {
        width: 30%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="master-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fixed"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is clever but doesn't apply to my situation. Sorry should have added more info. The container is sitting in a master container with a max width of 1200px. The fixed div will need to be 30% of this master max width container.

Comment: OK, so you could use a media query at `1200px` and switch the `width:calc(1200px * .3)` to `width: 30%;`

Comment: That is very smart. An the correct answer - I thought it wasn't possible! thanks x 1000

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `width: inherit;`

```css
.container {
    width: 30%;
    background: #444;
    height: 50px;
}

.fixed {
    width: inherit;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsf293Lz/)

Comment: Same as in linked questions, does not work, it's taking the inherit width of the body not it's parent, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t6d7aq1L/

Comment: If fit with your requirement, you can use `position: absolute;` to `.container` class like this https://jsfiddle.net/t6d7aq1L/1/

Comment: It does not work, your fixed div in your example is 30% width of the body not the parent div.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering why the two boxes are not the same width, it's because the `container` box is sizing to 30% of its parent `body`, whereas the `fixed` box is sized relative to the `html` element (and by default, `body` has a margin around the edge of the page, so `html` and `body` have different widths).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with percentage-based widths. As soon as you make an element fixed, its size and position attributes become relative to the *viewport*, not the parent element. It effectively 'breaks out' of its parent and becomes a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) so even though the CSS properties can still be inherited, it's calculated completely differently.

Your only option is to use a fixed width in pixels and use JS to sync the two if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set width in pixels to the .container or add width to .container parent.

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
}
```

or

```
<div class="containerparent">
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
  .container-parent {
        width: 100px;
    }

    .container {
        width: 30%;
    }
```