# child div with position fixed should have same width as parent div with position relative

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’d like to have a div's position fixed after scrolling. But when I change the position to `fixed` the div goes out of it’s container.
The div with the class `fixed` should be just as wide as the div with the class `relative`. The width of the parent div is dynamic. Only the max-width is known. No position sticky should be used.

I'm trying to achieve the following:
When you click a button, a form opens. the form should be fixed.

[image: sticky]

There are already some threads on this topic. However, the solutions didn't work for me.
It can also be solved with JS (but no JQuery).

[Set width of a "Position: fixed" div relative to parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565/set-width-of-a-position-fixed-div-relative-to-parent-div)

[Set width of fixed positioned div relative to his parent having max-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999846/set-width-of-fixed-positioned-div-relative-to-his-parent-having-max-width)

The following solutions didn't work for me:

- width: inherit
- max-width: inherit
- width: 100%

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 150vh;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
}

.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">
    <form class="fixed"></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `.sticky` and `<form class="fixed">` - start with fixing that

Comment: The form should be fixed in relation to what? And how are you sensing ‘after scrolling’?

Comment: `position: fixed` will move an element completely out of flow and position it fixed to the viewport. As it is out of flow it will no longer be affected by the parent `size`-wise. So you either need to define fixed width for both elements or use a script to get the width of an element and apply it to the other.

Comment: Did you consider `position:sticky`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit your max-width on both child elements, and on the last one apply width: 100%. And also apply your sticky class to the fixed div.

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 150vh;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 5;
  max-width: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">
    <form class="sticky"></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fixed div is wider than the parent div in this solution.

Comment: Because of the resolution, if you want to make it work with resolution changing, you should use width instead of max-width as limitator.

Answer (score 0):

**Understand Fixed: ([Full Blog Here](https://dev.to/phillt/inherit-the-width-of-the-parent-element-when-position-fixed-is-applied))**

"Unlike absolute, fixed doesn't position itself from its closest relative parent. Instead, fixed positions itself relative to the **viewport**. The **viewport will always stay fixed**, which is why you get the effect that you do.

That being said, whenever you "inherit" any width it will be **respective to the viewport**. So it does us no good when we're trying set the width of our target element to the width of it's parent"

Css fixed position is a bit tricky to play with, maybe you should consider using **position: sticky**. It remains relative to its parent element.

Try this:

```css
* {
        margin: 0%;
        padding: 0%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .relative {
        background-color: red;
        width: 50%;
        height: 350vh;
      }

      .absolute {
        background-color: blue;
        position: sticky;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 50%;
        height: 25vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .fixed {
        background-color: green;
        height: 50%;
        width: 80%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="relative">
   <div class="absolute">
      <form class="fixed"></form>
   </div>
</div>
```