# In css, how we can fixed width(in full 100% not in px) of a div which have property is position fixed

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

In css, how we can fixed width(in full 100% not in px) of a div which have property is position fixed inside the  div which already used postion absolute property.

let me know about its. this issue I am facing for long time.Is there any solution of this?

Comment: Would `left: 0;` `right: 0;` be enough for your case ?

Comment: is it `width:100vm` work for you ?

Comment: yes, but its not enough to fix it on all screens like in mobile too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but I find a solution on this post : [Set width of a "Position: fixed" div relative to parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565/set-width-of-a-position-fixed-div-relative-to-parent-div)

It use width:inherit

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  width:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">test</div>
</div>
```