# Position fixed with parent container width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a fixed header that fit it parent container.

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100wp;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px red solid;
 padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.sticky {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="sticky">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

It going out the container. So i tried inherit property :

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100wp;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px red solid;
 padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.sticky {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="sticky">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

And it doesn't fit too...

Is inherit property can't works with a percentage parent width ? If yes, how to manage that ?

Comment: You can't essentially. a fixed position div has only the viewport as a reference. I'd suggest you try `position:sticky` instead

Comment: hey specify your question in more details

Comment: Also note the typo `width: 100wp;`

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100627/8620333

Comment: Also duplicate from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565/set-width-of-a-position-fixed-div-relative-to-parent-div