# CSS: position: fixed and width 90% too wide

Tags: css, css-position

i'm using `position: fixed` and `width 90%` for a footer inside a overlay. The overlay and the footer are both 90% wider but the footer is wider. I guess it's because the footer ignores the scrollbar in chrome. Is there a way to solve this problem without JavaScript?

Here is quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/a15kpuL9/3/

The HTML:

```
<div class="modal hidden" data-modal-detail="5">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="body">
            <div id="inner-5" class="career-detail-inner-wrap"  >
                <div class="stickyFooter">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.stickyFooter {       
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.body {
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -7px 0 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

The Problem:
[image]

Comment: Putting something as fixed will remove it from the parent div so it won't be relative to that div, it will be relative to the screen. It would need to be absolute to be relative to the parent div.

Comment: Since i need to be sticked to bottom of the screen i need to adjust the width with JavaScript?

Comment: Can this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565/set-width-of-a-position-fixed-div-relative-to-parent-div

Comment: please tell me the other answer i put helps, also https://jsfiddle.net/q5b01yfz/

Comment: Nice! Good idea to use vw instead of %. That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the 90% to 90 vw instead. Here you go. :)

```css
.stickyFooter {
  width: 90vw;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.body {
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -7px 0 31px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 90vw;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 !important;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.career-detail-inner-wrap {
  background: green;
  height: 800px
}
```

```html
<div class="modal hidden" data-modal-detail="5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="body">
      <div id="inner-5" class="career-detail-inner-wrap">
        Inner
        <div class="stickyFooter">
          Sticky
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one less closing div , could that be the problem

```
<div class="modal hidden" data-modal-detail="5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="body">
        </div>
        <div id="inner-5" class="career-detail-inner-wrap"  >
            <div class="stickyFoooterSecond">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="modal hidden" data-modal-detail="5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="body">
        <div id="inner-5" class="career-detail-inner-wrap"  >
            <div class="stickyFoooterSecond">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just forgot to paste it. There are more markup than this, i just pasted the necessary party. ;)

Comment: Could you make a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: also where is stickyFooter class applied , is the stickyFooterSecond class doing something

Comment: Yes you are right. here is a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/a15kpuL9/3/

Comment: ya that helps, in shoort you want red and green div to be same width that is 90% of screen , correct ?